# How to save a ggplot so that it can entirely occupy a div with fixed height and width as background

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, shinyapps

I want to create a `Shiny` app where the `background picture` of a `div` will be some `ggplot` graph saved earlier. Below is one such prototype -

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)

# create and save plot
if (!file.exists("www")) dir.create("www")
ggsave(filename = "www/Some_Plot.png",
        ggplot(mpg, aes(class)) + geom_bar(),
        device = 'png')

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    div(style = "height: 550px; width: 550px; background: url('www/Some_Plot.png') no-repeat center center; background-size: cover;")
  ),
  server = function(input, output) {

  }
)
```

Given the `height` and `width` of the `div`, I want to have it's background as that `gg-plot` which should occupy entire `div` while maintaining `aspect ratio`.

Any pointer how that can be achieved will be highly helpful.

Thanks,

Comment: Since your `div` is of a fixed size, could you not just save your plot to be the same size as the `div` using the `width`, `height` and `units` arguments of `ggsave`? If not, maybe you could specify exactly what is not working with your example?

Comment: In th ggsave() there is no option to provide height and width in px. Besides, for some reason the 'Some_Plot.png' is not getting loaded as background

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why, but I couldn't get this to work on your example, but on my own little example. Sorry about that.

I removed the check for the directory. Presumably, you will only do that once and you will do it when you set up the app.

It seems that the key to getting it to work was in the CSS styling you applied. A Shiny application looks in the `www` folder by default, so specifying that in the styling meant that Shiny couldn't locate the image. If you look at my example, I only call the file-name since it is already placed in the correct folder.

```
# Load packages ----
pkgs <- c("shiny", "ggplot2")
invisible(lapply(pkgs, require, character.only = TRUE))

# Generate a plot ----
some_plot <- ggplot(mpg, aes(class)) +
  geom_bar()

ggsave(
  "www/some-plot.png",
  some_plot,
  device = "png"
)

# Define the user interface ----
ui <- fluidPage(
  div(
    style = "height: 550px; width = 550px;
             background: url('some-plot.png') no-repeat center center;
             background-size: cover;"
  )
)

# Define the server side ----
server <- function(input, output, session) {

}

# Combine into an app ----
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I did delete the file, restart RStudio and re-ran the app and it was able to create the image and render it as a background using CSS styling. Please try the same with your code (modified ofc) and mine. Maybe I did something incorrect modifying your code or you spot what I missed.